# How to make validation working in php

Tags: php, validation

I need to build a contact form and for that name ,email and query is mandatory. I have applied validation but somehow its not working at all. Here is my code for the same and it simply inserts the data and shows no error

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html lang="en" xml:lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset="iso-8859-1" />
<html>
<head>
<title>CP Mailer Form</title>
<style>
body, p, table, th, td, div {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
}
th {
  background-color:#0080C0;
  color:white;
  font-weight:bold;
  font-size:18px;
  border: 1px solid #0080C0;
}
input.text, textarea {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 11px;
  width: 99%;
}
.text:focus, textarea:focus {
  background-color: #FFFACC;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
}
#mydiv {
  margin-left: auto ;
  margin-right: auto ;
  width: 500px;
  text-align: left;
}
td.colone {
  text-align: right;
  vertical-align: top;
  padding-top:6px;
  width:20%;
}
td.coltwo {
  color:red;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: top;
  padding-top:9px;
}
td.colthree {
  width:80%
}
table.border {
  border: 1px solid #0080C0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="mydiv">
<form method="POST" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<!--<input type="hidden" value="index.php" name="referer">-->
<table class="border" width="500" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <th colspan="3" align="center">Mailer Form</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3"><div style="height:5px;"></div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="colone">Name</td>
    <td class="coltwo">*</td>
    <td class="colthree"><input class="text" type="text" name="username" value="<?php if(isset($name)) echo $name; ?>"style="width:98%;">
    <span class="error"><?php echo isset($nameErr) ? $nameErr : '' ;?></span>
    <br><br></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="colone">Email</td>
    <td class="coltwo">*</td>
    <td class="colthree"><input class="text" type="text" name="email" style="width:98%;">
    <span class="error"><?php echo isset($emailErr) ? $emailErr : '' ;?></span>
<br><br></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="colone">Mobile</td>
    <td class="coltwo">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="colthree"><input class="text" type="text" name="mobile" style="width:98%;">
    </td>

    </td>
  </tr>

   <tr>
    <td class="colone">Company</td>
    <td class="coltwo">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="colthree"><input class="text" type="text" name="company" style="width:98%;"></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td class="colone">Designation</td>
    <td class="coltwo">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="colthree"><input class="text" type="text" name="designation" style="width:98%;"></td>
  </tr>

  <!--<tr>
    <td class="colone">Contact by</td>
    <td class="coltwo">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="colthree">
      <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
          <td width="1">
            <select size="1" name="frmContactBy">
            <option value="Telephone">Telephone</option>
            <option value="Email">Email</option>
            </select>
          </td>
          <td>
            <select size="1" name="frmBestTime">
            <option value="Morning">in Morning</option>
            <option value="Afternoon">in Afternoon</option>
            <option value="Evening">in Evening</option>
            </select>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>-->
  <tr>
    <td class="colone">Your query</td>
    <td class="coltwo">*</td>
    <td class="colthree"><textarea class="text" name="query" style="width:98%;height:100px;"></textarea><span class="error"><?php echo isset($queryErr) ? $queryErr : '' ;?></span>
<br><br></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="colone" colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="colthree"><input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit"><input type="reset" value="Reset" name="reset"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3"><div style="height:5px;"></div></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</form>
<span style="color:red;">*</span> = required<br />
</div>
</body>
</html>

<?php


// define variables and set to empty values


if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    $nameErr = $emailErr = $queryErr = "";
    $name = $email = $query = "";

    if(isset($_POST['name'])){
        $username = $_POST['name'];
    } else {
        $nameErr = 'Enter name <br />';
    }

    echo  $nameErr;

     if(isset($_POST['email'])){
        $email = $_POST['email'];
    } else {
        $emailErr = 'Enter email <br />';
    }

    echo  $emailErr;

     if(isset($_POST['query'])){
        $query = $_POST['query'];
    } else {
        $queryErr = 'Enter your query <br />';
    }

    echo  $queryErr;

}

//if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
  //if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
   // $nameErr = "Name is required";
//  } else {
   // $name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
  //}

 // if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
    //$emailErr = "Email is required";
  //} else {
  // $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
 // }

  //if (empty($_POST["website"])) {
    //$website = "";
  //} else {
   // $website = test_input($_POST["website"]);
 // }

  //if (empty($_POST["query"])) {
 //   $query = "";
 // } else {
 //   $query = test_input($_POST["query"]);
  //}

  //if (empty($_POST["gender"])) {
    //$genderErr = "Gender is required";
  //} else {
    //$gender = test_input($_POST["gender"]);
  //}
//}

// Only process the form if $_POST isn't empty


  // Connect to MySQL
  $mysqli = new mysqli( 'localhost', 'root', '', 'mailer' );

  // Check our connection
  if ( $mysqli->connect_error ) {
    die( 'Connect Error: ' . $mysqli->connect_errno . ': ' . $mysqli->connect_error );
  }
   if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $mobile = $_POST['mobile'];
        $company = $_POST['company'];
        $designation = $_POST['designation'];
        $query = $_POST['query'];

  // Insert our data
  $sql = "INSERT INTO user ( name,email, mobile,company,designation,query ) VALUES ( '$name','$email','$mobile','$company','$designation','$query')";
  $insert = $mysqli->query($sql);
   }
  // Print response from MySQL
  if (isset ($insert)) {
     header('Location: thankyou.php');
  } else {
    die();
  }

  // Close our connection
  $mysqli->close();

  function test_input($data) {
  $data = trim($data);
  $data = stripslashes($data);
  $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
  return $data;
}

?>
```

Comment: put your php before html , remove `echo  $nameErr;` these type of echo.

Comment: When you get a chance, Google SQL injection.

Comment: adding php before html gives a blank page. @Noman

Comment: @Jeff Thanks mate.. I appreciate and will look forward to it.

Comment: try to remove die() to get the rest of the page processed

Comment: @Richard Hey thanks Rich.. but what to give as "else" if the insert is not succesful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code

```
<?php
// define variables and set to empty values

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    $usernameErr = $emailErr = $queryErr = "";
    $username = $email = $query = "";
    $toterr = 0;

    if(isset($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['username'])){
        $username = test_input($_POST['username']);
    } else {
        $usernameErr = 'Enter username <br />';
        $toterr++;
    }    

    if(isset($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['email']) && filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
        $email = test_input($_POST['email']);
    } else {
        $emailErr = 'Enter valid email <br />';
        $toterr++;
    }    

    if(isset($_POST['query']) && !empty($_POST['query'])){
        $query = test_input($_POST['query']);
    } else {
        $queryErr = 'Enter your query <br />';
        $toterr++;
    }

    $mobile = isset($_POST['mobile']) ? test_input($_POST['mobile']) : '';
    $company = isset($_POST['company']) ? test_input($_POST['company']) : '';
    $designation = isset($_POST['designation']) ? test_input($_POST['designation']) : '';


    if($toterr == 0)
    {
        // Connect to MySQL
        $mysqli = new mysqli( 'localhost', 'root', '', 'test' );
        // Check our connection
        if ( $mysqli->connect_error ) {
          die( 'Connect Error: ' . $mysqli->connect_errno . ': ' . $mysqli->connect_error );
        }

        // Insert our data
        $sql = "INSERT INTO user ( name,email, mobile,company,designation,query ) VALUES ( '$username','$email','$mobile','$company','$designation','$query')";
        $insert = $mysqli->query($sql);

        // Print response from MySQL
        if ($insert) {
           header('Location: thankyou.php');
        } 
        else {
          echo '<script>alert(\'data not saved\')</script>';
        }
        // Close our connection
        $mysqli->close();
    }    

}

function test_input($data) 
{
  $data = trim($data);
  $data = stripslashes($data);
  $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
  return $data;
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html lang="en" xml:lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>CP Mailer Form</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html" charset="iso-8859-1" />
<style>
body, p, table, th, td, div {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
}
th {
  background-color:#0080C0;
  color:white;
  font-weight:bold;
  font-size:18px;
  border: 1px solid #0080C0;
}
input.text, textarea {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 11px;
  width: 99%;
}
.text:focus, textarea:focus {
  background-color: #FFFACC;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
}
#mydiv {
  margin-left: auto ;
  margin-right: auto ;
  width: 500px;
  text-align: left;
}
td.colone {
  text-align: right;
  vertical-align: top;
  padding-top:6px;
  width:20%;
}
td.coltwo {
  color:red;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: top;
  padding-top:9px;
}
td.colthree {
  width:80%
}
table.border {
  border: 1px solid #0080C0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
.error{
  color:red;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="mydiv">
<form method="POST" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<!--<input type="hidden" value="index.php" name="referer">-->
<table class="border" width="500" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <th colspan="3" align="center">Mailer Form</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3"><div style="height:5px;"></div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="colone">Name</td>
    <td class="coltwo">*</td>
    <td class="colthree"><input class="text" type="text" name="username" value="<?php if(isset($username)) echo $username; ?>"style="width:98%;">
    <span class="error"><?php echo isset($usernameErr) ? $usernameErr : '' ;?></span>
    <br><br></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="colone">Email</td>
    <td class="coltwo">*</td>
    <td class="colthree"><input class="text" type="text" name="email" value="<?php if(isset($email)) echo $email; ?>" style="width:98%;">
    <span class="error"><?php echo isset($emailErr) ? $emailErr : '' ;?></span>
<br><br></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="colone">Mobile</td>
    <td class="coltwo">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="colthree"><input class="text" type="text" name="mobile" value="<?php if(isset($mobile)) echo $mobile; ?>" style="width:98%;">
    </td>

    </td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td class="colone">Company</td>
    <td class="coltwo">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="colthree"><input class="text" type="text" name="company" value="<?php if(isset($company)) echo $company; ?>" style="width:98%;"></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td class="colone">Designation</td>
    <td class="coltwo">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="colthree"><input class="text" type="text" name="designation" value="<?php if(isset($designation)) echo $designation; ?>" style="width:98%;"></td>
  </tr>  
  <tr>
    <td class="colone">Your query</td>
    <td class="coltwo">*</td>
    <td class="colthree"><textarea class="text" name="query" style="width:98%;height:100px;"><?php if(isset($query)) echo $query; ?></textarea><span class="error"><?php echo isset($queryErr) ? $queryErr : '' ;?></span>
<br><br></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="colone" colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="colthree"><input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit"><input type="submit" value="Reset" name="reset"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3"><div style="height:5px;"></div></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</form>
<span style="color:red;">*</span> = required<br />
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: A heartly thanks @knowledgeBase. U saved my day.. Spread the help always. Its working completely fine. Kudos n cheers

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php
$nameErr = $emailErr = $queryErr = "";
$name = $email = $query = "";

if(isset($_POST['username'])){
    $name = trim($_POST['username']);
}
if(isset($_POST['email'])){
    $email = trim($_POST['email']);
}
if(isset($_POST['query'])){
    $query = trim($_POST['query']);
}

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    if($name==''){
        $nameErr = 'Enter name <br />';
    }
    if($email==''){
        $emailErr = 'Enter email <br />';
    }elseif(!preg_match('/^([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})$/i',$email)){
        $emailErr = 'Incorrect email <br />';
    }
    if($query==''){
        $queryErr = 'Enter your query <br />';
    }
    if($nameErr.$emailErr.$queryErr!=''){
        echo $nameErr.$emailErr.$queryErr;
    }else{
        //DATABASE INSERT AND REDIRECTION GOES HERE!
    }
}
?><!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html lang="en" xml:lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset="iso-8859-1" />
<html>
<head>
<title>CP Mailer Form</title>
<style>
body, p, table, th, td, div {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
}
th {
  background-color:#0080C0;
  color:white;
  font-weight:bold;
  font-size:18px;
  border: 1px solid #0080C0;
}
input.text, textarea {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 11px;
  width: 99%;
}
.text:focus, textarea:focus {
  background-color: #FFFACC;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
}
#mydiv {
  margin-left: auto ;
  margin-right: auto ;
  width: 500px;
  text-align: left;
}
td.colone {
  text-align: right;
  vertical-align: top;
  padding-top:6px;
  width:20%;
}
td.coltwo {
  color:red;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: top;
  padding-top:9px;
}
td.colthree {
  width:80%
}
table.border {
  border: 1px solid #0080C0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="mydiv">
<form method="POST" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<!--<input type="hidden" value="index.php" name="referer">-->
<table class="border" width="500" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <th colspan="3" align="center">Mailer Form</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3"><div style="height:5px;"></div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="colone">Name</td>
    <td class="coltwo">*</td>
    <td class="colthree"><input class="text" type="text" name="username" value="<?php if(isset($name)) echo htmlspecialchars($name); ?>" style="width:98%;">
    <span class="error"><?php echo isset($nameErr) ? $nameErr : '' ;?></span>
    <br><br></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="colone">Email</td>
    <td class="coltwo">*</td>
    <td class="colthree"><input class="text" type="text" name="email" value="<?php if(isset($email)) echo htmlspecialchars($email); ?>" style="width:98%;">
    <span class="error"><?php echo isset($emailErr) ? $emailErr : '' ;?></span>
<br><br></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="colone">Mobile</td>
    <td class="coltwo">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="colthree"><input class="text" type="text" name="mobile" style="width:98%;">
    </td>

    </td>
  </tr>

   <tr>
    <td class="colone">Company</td>
    <td class="coltwo">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="colthree"><input class="text" type="text" name="company" style="width:98%;"></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td class="colone">Designation</td>
    <td class="coltwo">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="colthree"><input class="text" type="text" name="designation" style="width:98%;"></td>
  </tr>

  <!--<tr>
    <td class="colone">Contact by</td>
    <td class="coltwo">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="colthree">
      <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
          <td width="1">
            <select size="1" name="frmContactBy">
            <option value="Telephone">Telephone</option>
            <option value="Email">Email</option>
            </select>
          </td>
          <td>
            <select size="1" name="frmBestTime">
            <option value="Morning">in Morning</option>
            <option value="Afternoon">in Afternoon</option>
            <option value="Evening">in Evening</option>
            </select>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>-->
  <tr>
    <td class="colone">Your query</td>
    <td class="coltwo">*</td>
    <td class="colthree"><textarea class="text" name="query" style="width:98%;height:100px;"><?php if(isset($query)) echo htmlspecialchars($query); ?></textarea><span class="error"><?php echo isset($queryErr) ? $queryErr : '' ;?></span>
<br><br></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="colone" colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="colthree"><input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit"><input type="reset" value="Reset" name="reset"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3"><div style="height:5px;"></div></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</form>
<span style="color:red;">*</span> = required<br />
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a ton @gdmt.. Things are working pretty fine but the name variable is not getting saved in database and it redirects to thankyou page without saving the name. If i can get a fix on this

Comment: Be careful stripslashes() is not SQL injection safe that's why I did not copy it into this solution. The other answer does save and redirect but it's as insecure as your original code regarding SQL injections.